# Universal Package artifact - use package view in pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a release pipeline that is triggered whenever a new version of a Universal Package is published. Now, as my package can be promoted to a specific view (defaults are @local, @prereleas or @release), I'd like to use the selected view in a custom condition for the subsequent steps in my pipeline.

Something like :

> eq($(hopefullysomepredefinedvar), '@prerelease')

However, I checked the available pre-defined variables and the 'view' information doesn't seem to be available unless I missed something.

An even cleaner solution would probably be to use separate stages in the release pipeline and evaluate the 'view' through some pre-deployment condition, but I didn't find a way to do that.

Finally, I tried to add the same artifact (Universal Package) multiple times, with different 'views' to 'filter' on. So once with view @prerelease and once with view @release. However, it seems like my pipeline does not get triggered at all with this configuration.

Is there a solution (or a good workaround) for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can write a script through [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details/get%20package%20version?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#feedviewtype) to judge the package view. If there is a view named `Prerelease`, set the `condition` variable to `true`.

```
GET https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/Packages/{packageId}/versions/{packageVersionId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Sample script:

```
$url = 'GET https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/Packages/{packageId}/versions/{packageVersionId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1';
$token = "PAT"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))   

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json 

$results = $response.views.name
       
foreach($view in $response.views){
    
        if($view.name -eq "Prerelease"){   
            $condition = "true"          
       }
}

Write-Host "results = $($results | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
Write-Host "result = $condition"
```

Then you can set custom condition like this `eq($(condition), true)`.

**The second workaround**:

Add multiple artifact source and then we specify the Source alias like below:

[image]

We can use the `Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias` [default variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---release) to get the alias of the artifact which triggered the release in the condition to judge the view.

For example: `condition: contains(variables['Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias'], '@prerelease' ))`

Comment: Afaik the API assumes I know the version number, right? In the release pipeline artifact that triggers the pipeline I just specify 'Latest' and I seem to remember having read somewhere that the API doesn't support that.

Comment: `I just specify 'Latest'` You can try this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details/get%20package?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). [The default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9cyG.png) is the latest version.

Comment: ok, I'll give that a try. I just figured that I also have the version that triggered the pipeline from the triggering artifacts variables, e.g.  [BUILD_BUILDID] --> [0.5.0] so I could even pass that onto the API.

Comment: The API call works fine. The only problem with this approach is that if I remove the view 'filter' from the artifact trigger, the pipeline only gets triggered when a new version of the package is published and not when the version is promoted to a specific view.

Comment: If you want the pipeline to be triggered when the version is promoted to a specific view, why do you remove view 'filter' from the artifact trigger? In addition, I added another workaround in the answer, please view it.